# tx queue failed to flush error on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: networking, server, kernel, asus

I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS on my laptop, an Asus TP500LA. I have it connected to wifi with the installed **MediaTek MT7630E** wifi card. It runs fine for about a day, then it becomes unresponsive.

`kern.log` becomes filled with the same error:

```
May  8 00:26:47 Claire kernel: [88167.420227] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
May  8 00:26:47 Claire kernel: [88167.456229] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0
May  8 00:26:48 Claire kernel: [88168.640196] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
```

This error repeats every couple of seconds, until I reboot it. It becomes so overloaded with this that the monitor starts being flooded with the error as well. Then I can't `ssh` in, I just have to reboot manually.

I have scoured the internet, and found people with the same problem, but it seems all the threads get cut short, or the solutions are way too tech-heavy for me, creating custom drivers and doing things that I don't know how to do, with no explanation.

```
$ cat /proc/version

Linux version 4.4.0-77-generic (buildd@lgw01-59) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 26 08:34:02 UTC 2017


$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e074]
        Kernel driver in use: mt7630e
        Kernel modules: wl, mt7630e



$ iwconfig     #asterisks for privacy

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0f0  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"BTHub*-****"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: **:**:**:**:**
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=56 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:5   Missed beacon:0

enp2s0f1  no wireless extensions.

$ iw reg get

country GB: DFS-ETSI
        (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
        (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
        (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

Here's `kern.log` leading up to the error:

```
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.685504] ===>rt2800_sta_remove:MT7630
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.685515] BtAFHCtl: COEX AFH Start Ch = 0, AFH End Ch = 0, Channel = 6, CentralChannel = 6
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.685517] SendAndesAFH: -->
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.685519] SendAndesAFH: LinkStatus = 2, BW = 1, Channel = 6, BssHashID = 1, PktLength = 20
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.685522] AsicSendCmdToAndes not need  Rsp!!!
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.685525] PCIKickOutCmd (TxCpuIdx = 16)
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.685527] SendAndesAFH: <--
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.685553] ==>INT_SOURCE_CSR_7630_HCCA_DMA_DONE
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.690495] ===>rt2800_sta_remove:MT7630   0x80100 = 0x0
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.690497] ===>rt2800_sta_remove:MT7630   0x80100 = 0x0
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716114] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716118] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716119] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716122] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716124] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716125] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716127] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716129] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716131] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716133] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:17 Claire kernel: [87297.716134] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.849852] wlp3s0f0: authenticate with 00:a4:23:1d:e4:a8
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.865471] wlp3s0f0: send auth to 00:a4:23:1d:e4:a8 (try 1/3)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.867317] wlp3s0f0: authenticated
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.869452] wlp3s0f0: associate with 00:a4:23:1d:e4:a8 (try 1/3)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879184] wlp3s0f0: RX AssocResp from 00:a4:23:1d:e4:a8 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879196] ===>rt2800_sta_add:MT7630
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879215] ===>rt2800_sta_add:MT7630   wcid=33
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879216] Connect to AP MAC: 00:a4:23:1d:e4:a8 WCID=33
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879222] BtAFHCtl: COEX AFH Start Ch = 11, AFH End Ch = 59, Channel = 6, CentralChannel = 6
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879224] SendAndesAFH: -->
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879225] SendAndesAFH: LinkStatus = 1, BW = 1, Channel = 6, BssHashID = 1, PktLength = 20
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879227] AsicSendCmdToAndes not need  Rsp!!!
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879230] PCIKickOutCmd (TxCpuIdx = 17)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879232] SendAndesAFH: <--
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879233] SendAndesWLANStatus: -->
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879235] SendAndesWLANStatus: CoexOperation = 4, WlanStatus = 15, PrivilegeTime = 0, BssHashID = 1, PktLength = 16
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879238] ==>INT_SOURCE_CSR_7630_HCCA_DMA_DONE
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879248] AsicSendCmdToAndes not need  Rsp!!!
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879249] PCIKickOutCmd (TxCpuIdx = 18)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879256] ==>INT_SOURCE_CSR_7630_HCCA_DMA_DONE
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884714] BtAFHCtl: COEX AFH Start Ch = 11, AFH End Ch = 59, Channel = 6, CentralChannel = 6
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884716] SendAndesAFH: -->
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884717] SendAndesAFH: LinkStatus = 1, BW = 1, Channel = 6, BssHashID = 1, PktLength = 20
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884718] AsicSendCmdToAndes not need  Rsp!!!
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884720] PCIKickOutCmd (TxCpuIdx = 19)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884721] SendAndesAFH: <--
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879233] SendAndesWLANStatus: -->
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879235] SendAndesWLANStatus: CoexOperation =
 4, WlanStatus = 15, PrivilegeTime = 0, BssHashID = 1, PktLength = 16
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879238] ==>INT_SOURCE_CSR_7630_HCCA_DMA_DONE
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879248] AsicSendCmdToAndes not need  Rsp!!!
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879249] PCIKickOutCmd (TxCpuIdx = 18)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.879256] ==>INT_SOURCE_CSR_7630_HCCA_DMA_DONE
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884714] BtAFHCtl: COEX AFH Start Ch = 11, AF
H End Ch = 59, Channel = 6, CentralChannel = 6
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884716] SendAndesAFH: -->
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884717] SendAndesAFH: LinkStatus = 1, BW = 1
, Channel = 6, BssHashID = 1, PktLength = 20
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884718] AsicSendCmdToAndes not need  Rsp!!!
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884720] PCIKickOutCmd (TxCpuIdx = 19)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884721] SendAndesAFH: <--
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.884728] ==>INT_SOURCE_CSR_7630_HCCA_DMA_DONE
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.889737] wlp3s0f0: associated
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.892244] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed
to country: GB
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.892247] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.892249] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @
 bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.892252] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 K
Hz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.892254] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 K
Hz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.892256] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 K
Hz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.892258] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 K
Hz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
May  8 00:12:18 Claire kernel: [87298.892259] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000
 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.156181] ===>rt2800_sta_remove:MT7630
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.156190] BtAFHCtl: COEX AFH Start Ch = 0, AFH End Ch = 0, Channel = 6, CentralChannel = 6
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.156193] SendAndesAFH: -->
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.156196] SendAndesAFH: LinkStatus = 2, BW = 1, Channel = 6, BssHashID = 1, PktLength = 20
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.156199] AsicSendCmdToAndes not need  Rsp!!!
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.156204] PCIKickOutCmd (TxCpuIdx = 20)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.156206] SendAndesAFH: <--
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.161176] ===>rt2800_sta_remove:MT7630   0x80100 = 0x0
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.161178] ===>rt2800_sta_remove:MT7630   0x80100 = 0x0
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.328083] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342618] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342622] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342624] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342626] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342628] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342630] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342632] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342634] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342635] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342637] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:57 Claire kernel: [87338.342639] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
May  8 00:12:58 Claire kernel: [87338.588073] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
May  8 00:12:58 Claire kernel: [87338.748069] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
May  8 00:12:59 Claire kernel: [87339.968027] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
May  8 00:13:04 Claire kernel: [87344.959890] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
May  8 00:13:04 Claire kernel: [87345.119856] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
May  8 00:13:05 Claire kernel: [87346.339824] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
May  8 00:13:10 Claire kernel: [87351.335676] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
```